# How well can professional oboe players tremolo between G/B and Eb/G?

Tags: fingering, tremolo, oboe

How likely are professional oboe players to be able to execute this?  The goal is the fastest possible alternation between the notes.  I don't know a ton about oboe, but the Oboe 2 tremolo looks easy enough after consulting a fingering chart; just two left-hand fingers move.  The Oboe 1 one looks a little fishy with more fingers to move.  But do pro players have enough tricks up their sleeve that they can make it work?

If it matters, the texture here is very dense, loud, and dissonant so it doesn't have to be *pretty.*  Dynamic is ***ff.***

[image]

Comment: There _are_ lots of good-enough alternative fingerings (which I've long forgotten, unfortunately) that probably a clever oboist could move even just _one_ finger if speed were the most important thing... But, sadly, I do not recall enough details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those tremolos are easy for oboists at almost any level. The G-B tremolo involves just two fingers moving together. Eb-G requires three fingers to move together, the player can leave the E-flat key down.
It they're moving together rather than in opposite directions, it's as fast to move three fingers as it is to move one.

On woodwind instruments in general trills and tremolos are easy if they only involve adjacent fingers of one hand moving in the same direction. They get harder if the fingers are not adjacent and the finger between them stays down. They get harder still if the fingers of both hands are involved, and even harder if fingers are moving in opposite directions (lifting one finger at the same time as depressing another). The hardest trills/tremolos are those where one finger has to move between two different keys.
Instruments are generally built with extra 'trill' keys to help with the most difficult trills and some, but not all, of the most difficult tremolos.
There are very often alternative fingerings available for some tills/tremolos, often at the cost of sub-standard intonation or tone quality.

Professional players will usually produce a satisfactory result from almost anything you throw at them.

Comment: Normally Eb is produced by half-covering with the first finger left hand whereas the G uses the first octave key. It would be very difficult to alternate between these at speed, but in practice the first octave key can be used for both.

Comment: @TomSharpe Either the half-hole or the octave key can be used for both notes, plus it's also possible to leave RH3 down.